# What kind of structure with a relative pronoun is this?

Tags: legalese, relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, whose, pied-piping

> As Lord Esher once noted, ‘Any proposition **the result of which** would be to show that the common law of England is wholly unreasonable and unjust cannot be part of the common law of
>   England.’

Would someone please help unravel the bolded relative clause, step-by-step? Please explain your steps. I've never seen this construct before.

Does the bolded clause = 'whose result'?

Moreover, is it equivalent to '**the result of** any proposition **which** would be to show ...' ?

Source: P101, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The technical term for this construction is ***Pied-Piping***.
  (I don't make up these names, honest; this one, like many others, is due to [Haj Ross](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/haj/))
Here's how it works:

Relative clauses modify nouns; these nouns are called **antecedents** (because they "go before").
Every relative clause contains an anaphor of its antecedent, which becomes a relative pronoun,
and, under certain circumstances, may simply be deleted.

- [*`the man`* [`the man` *came to dinner*]] --> [*`the man`* [`who/that` *came to dinner*]]
- [*`the man`* [*I saw* `the man`]] --> [*`the man`* [`who/that` *I saw*]] --> [*`the man`* [*I saw*]]

In the first example above, the relative pronoun is the subject and may not be deleted.
In the second example, the relative pronoun is the direct object and may be deleted.
That accounts for the majority of relative clauses.

However, subject and object do not exhaust the roles or positions of nouns.
Other roles are called *Oblique*, as a class, and include objects of prepositions, of all sorts.
In the following examples, I'll leave out the `who/that` version, which is always possible,

- [*`the man`* [*I looked at* `the man`]] --> [*`the man`* [`who/that` *I looked at*]]

because oblique relative pronouns are always deletable.
(Note that these all end up stranding a preposition at the end, just like the one above does):

- [*`the man`* [*I looked at* `the man`]] --> [*`the man`* [*I looked at*]]
- [*`the man`* [*I talked to* `the man`]] --> [*`the man`* [*I talked to*]]
- [*`the man`* [*I came with* `the man`]] --> [*`the man`* [*I came with*]]
- [*`the room`* [*I live in* `the room`]] --> [*`the room`* [*I live in*]]

In effect, moving or deleting the relative pronoun breaks up the prepositional phrase.
However, prepositional phrases are constituents, and may **optionally** be moved as one unit:

- [`the man` [*I looked* [`at the man`]]] --> [`the man` [[`at whom`] *I looked*]]
- [`the room` [*I live* [`in the room`]]] --> [`the room` [[`in which`] *I live*]]

This process, of moving the whole prepositional phrase instead of only its object,
is what *Pied-Piping* means. The preposition gets piped away to the front, lining up with its object, instead of being stranded at the end of the sentence, objectless.

Moreover, prepositional phrases can modify nouns that are objects of other prepositional phrases, and **they, too,** are constituents, and can be moved as a unit. So are, and so can, the noun phrases. Again, only **optionally**. Which leads to such mind-numbing spectra of nonrestrictive relatives as:

- *The government prescribes the height of the lettering on the covers of the reports.*
- *the reports, **which** the government prescribes the height of the lettering on the covers of*
- *the reports, of **which** the government prescribes the height of the lettering on the covers*
- *the reports, the covers of **which** the government prescribes the height of the lettering on*
- *the reports, on the covers of **which** the government prescribes the height of the lettering*
- *the reports, the lettering on the covers of **which** the government prescribes the height of*
- *the reports, of the lettering on the covers of **which** the government prescribes the height*
- *the reports, the height of the lettering on the covers of **which** the government prescribes*

This kind of syntax seems especially common in pedantic, bureaucratic, or legal contexts.
Opinions vary as to the grammaticality of various portions of the spectrum; pied-piping seems
to be a syntactic habit one picks up, if at all, later in one's education, and individually. I.e, ***YMMV***.

Comment: Nice! Love your exhaustive reply.

Comment: Exhaustive? I didn't begin [to cover the topic](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=pied+piping).

Comment: ..........Rats.

Comment: Well, it exhausted *me*, reading it! LOL

Comment: +1. Thank you effusively for your care, detail, and every step. Are there any names or terms for this kind of analysis or decomposition?

Comment: It's called Generative Grammar. If you want to know how to do it, it's all in Jim McCawley's _[The Syntactic Phenomena of English](http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Syntactic_Phenomena_of_English.html?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC)_ (U Chicago Press 1998). Pied Piping was either discovered or invented (depending on what church you go to) by Haj Ross in his 1967 MIT dissertation, _[Constraints on Variables in Syntax](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Ross_1967.html)_.

Comment: I thought it was Robin Lakoff who came up with the term "pied piping".  (There is a book version of Ross's dissertation -- I think it's **Infinite Syntax**.)

Comment: Maybe. I don't remember.

Comment: I understand why it's called pied-piping. But it only applies if you do it, doesn't it? How can utterances such as A. "The book of which I speak" versus B. "The book I speak of" be that unless you have actually moved it? There seems to be an "infinity loop" here. I think it is merely a tool of analysis that demonstrates flexibility. Are these only definable in reference to each other? [I guess everything in linguistics is ultimately contrastive....:)].

Comment: All optional rules only apply if they are applied, yes. If you want a step-by-step linkage between _A_ and _B_ above, it's called a derivation, and it can be provided. All syntax is tools of analysis; I don't understand your objection, if that's what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Did anyone answer the last question: "Moreover, is it equivalent to 'the result of any proposition which would be to show ...' ?"  Assuming "it" refers to the quote:

‘Any proposition the result of which would be to show that the common law of England is wholly unreasonable and unjust cannot be part of the common law of England.’

then, no, I don't see a way of filling in the dots to make "the result ..." equivalent.  Instead, the original quote is equivalent to:

If any proposition has the result that the common law of England is wholly unreasonable and unjust, then that proposition cannot be part of the common law of England.

Part of the derivation of the original is to convert the antecedent of the if-then construction to a relative clause, which is then attached to the subject of the consequent of the if-then clause.

It's all a fancified way of saying that, in law, the common law is assumed to be consistent with itself.

Answer (score 1):

As to your question:

"Does the bolded clause = 'whose result'? "

The answer is Yes.

"... is it equivalent to 'the result of any proposition which would be to show ...' ?"

Again, yes.

I don't quite know how you would unravel the original clause "step by step".  It seems to be a matter of a single-step.

**Edited to Add:**

"..please explain how you determined the meaning of the original clause?"  This is a difficult thing to do.  I did not have to "determine" the meaning -- I understood it innately.  I think if you need a detailed explanation, @JohnLawler's response is probably what you want.

Comment: According to some authorities, *who*, and hence *whose*, can only be used of people, not objects like propositions. So not strictly equal, but probably close enough for OPs purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you please explain how you determined the meaning of the original clause? I guessed. Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as comments?

Comment: Yes: though some, presumably including Lord Esher, regard *whose* as inappropriate in cases like this where the relative pronoun's antecedent is not one or more *persons,* still it has the unique advantage of being both a relative pronoun *and* in the possessive or genitive case. And if *whose* is rejected as inappropriate, the admittedly rather awkward periphrasis shown in bold is a fallback choice. Better yet, perhaps, *"No* proposition that *implies* that the common law of England is wholly unreasonable and unjust *can* itself be part of the common law of England."

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Would you like to recast as a separate answer for which I can upvote?

Comment: ‘Any proposition the result of which would be to show =Any proposition that results or resulting in showing. Same thing.