# By which? - Problem with relative clause

Tags: grammar, prepositions, relative-clauses, which-who, by-on

for hours I've been scouring the internet for some sentences/grammar rules which bother me. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the answer, and that's why I decided to ask here.

- Are sentences 1) and 2) correct? If not then why? Is sentence nr 5)
  the best way (and the most natural way for a native speaker) to
  express the idea?

" to go **by** a train

1. 1) The train **by** which I went was delayed
2. 2) the train **by**
       which I travelled was delayed
3. 3) The train which I went **by** was
           delayed
4. 4) The train which I travelled **by** was delayed
5. 5) The
                   train I travelled/was on was delayed"

Best regards

Comment: All 5 are grammatical. The technical term for you're looking for is [Pied-Piping](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299).

Answer (score 1):

"to go by a train"
I think the first problem is that we don't say "to go by a train" - the expression is "to go by train" (to go by car, bus, road, plane).

I personally would never use "travelled by the/a train" in this context either - I travelled by the train (that left at 10:00/that was delayed) sounds strange, though is perhaps ok (see comment below) - I (again personally) would be more likely to say I travelled with, or I was on, or I took.

Google, however, produces lots of examples of "the train by which" so I guess
"the train by which I was travelling/travelled was delayed" - is also correct

Alternatives:

- The train I was on was delayed
- The train I was travelling on was delayed
- My train was delayed

I went by a train means I walked past a train to my (Irish) ears...

Edit: "the train by which I travelled" gets just over 5000 hits; "the train by which I was travelling" only six! ("traveled": 3350; "was traveling": one) - so actually not so common after all - made a mistake when I said "lots of examples" above.

Answer (score 1):

### The Main Clause

All five (six actually) constructions clearly communicate the main idea:

> *The train was delayed.*

---

### The Relative Clause

All five relative clause constructions also clearly communicate *I was traveling on the train* that was delayed:

> 1) *by which I went*:

*Train* is modified by *I went*, using *which* as the [object of the prepositional phrase](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/relative-clauses):

> - When we use whom or **which** the preposition sometimes comes at the beginning of the clause:
>
> You were talking about a book. I haven’t read it. >>>... *I haven’t read the book **about which** you were talking.*

This is a perfectly legitimate construction, even though it can sound awkward.

> 2) by which I travelled

*Train* is modified by *I traveled*, using *which* as the object of the prepositional phrase. Again, a perfectly legitimate construction, replacing *went* with the equivalent verb *travelled*.

> 3) which I went by

*Train* is modified by *I went*, using *which* as the object of the prepositional phrase, with the [preposition following the verb phrase](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/relative-clauses):

> - as object of a preposition. When the relative pronoun is the object of
>     a preposition we usually put the preposition after the verb ...
>
> You were talking about a book. I haven’t read it. >>> I haven’t
>   read the book **which** you were talking **about**.

It is perfectly acceptable to put the preposition after the verb in a relative clause.

> 4) which I travelled by

*Train* is modified by *I traveled*, using *which* as the object of the prepositional phrase, replacing *went* with the equivalent verb *travelled*.

> 5a) I travelled on

*Train* is modified by *I traveled*, [reducing](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/relative-clauses) *which* from the prepositional phrase:

> - When the relative pronoun is the object of a preposition we usually leave it out:
>
> That’s the house my parents live in.

The missing relative pronoun is clearly understood.

> 5b) I was on

*Train* is modified by *I was*, reducing *which* from the prepositional phrase, replacing *travelled* with the verb *was*. *I went by* would work but it might create a little confusion between ***walking*** by the train (local), and ***traveling*** by the train (instrumental).

---

### The Prepositions

Although *by* would not work with the verb *was*, both *by* and *on* work just fine with both *travelled* and *went*.

Answer (score 0):

*My train was delayed* - is probably the most natural way for a native speaker to express the idea.

Answer (score -1):

1 is no good.  2 is a little better than 1.  3 is no good.  4 is a little better than 3.  5 is perfectly okay in both versions.

3 is interesting, because it sounds better when "that" is substituted for "which": "The train that I went by was delayed."  (Not good, but better.)  There is an analysis popular among syntacticians according to which relative "that" is not a pronoun, but rather is a relative clause introducer.  That suggests that what is wrong with 3 is, in part, removing the "which" from its original position in the by-phrase, because that doesn't happen with "that" (if it merely introduces the relative clause).

4 is also better with "that" instead of "which".

Comment: You are entitled to your opinion, Greg, but your opinion should be supported by reputable research or direct ELU reputation (like the 55K of John Lawler).

Comment: ... Reputation on ELU? You should read some of the articles Professor Lawler has authored! Though I admit, my downvote is not just because he says 'All 5 are grammatical', but because I think they are too. Though I'd only use the first two where I considered a formal register to be suitable.