# How to analyse "in which"?

Tags: grammar

> reference: part of something you say or write **in which** you mention a person or thing - [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/reference)

How can I analyse the phrase ***in which***?

I asked a similar question before - [Here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117205/how-can-i-understand-to-which-in-this-sentence)

However, this sentence is quite different from the previous one. In the previous case, *in which* was located right after a noun. So it was easy to find the subject of *in which* but it is located after a verb ("write") in this sentence. The only subject is *part of something*. If so, what's the meaning?

Here is my attempt. According to the previous answer,

1. reference is **part of something** you say or write
2. You mention a person or thing in **the part of something.**

I could understand these two sentences respectively but I'm struggling to find a relation between the two sentences. I think it's because of **in which**.

I mean,

1. reference is **part of something** you say or write
2. reference is **a person or thing** you mention.

These are more like acceptable to me.

Comment: Your first "2" is correct. Your last two alternatives are both incomplete - 2 is wrong because a reference isn't a person or a thing, it is a part of something you wrote. And 1 is incomplete because a reference isn't just any part of something you said or wrote, it is a part where you mentioned a person or a thing.

Comment: @RozennKeribin Thank you. hu.. it's very confusing. What's the main difference between "something you say or write" and "You mention a person or thing" Actually, "mention" and "say or write" are the same. I mean, if I said or wrote something, it means I already mentioned a person or a thing.

Comment: Not really; "mention" is specifically talking or writing about an external entity, in the context of a larger piece of writing or talking. And it will typically be short - so if I say a 2-hour speech mentioned climate change, all I'm saying is that the words "climate change" occurred at least once in that speech. "Something you say or write" is completely generic; it can include gibberish that means nothing, it can include many different subjects, it can have many different purposes. "A mention" is, *within* something you say or write, a subset that relates to one specific external entity.

Comment: Typically, in something you say or write you will mention many different things. The thing you say or write can cover an arbitrary number of subjects, but a "mention" will be about one specific thing. And you can have parts of what you say or write that don't "mention" anything external in particular, that aren't a reference. Like "Hello" for example.

Comment: 'part of something you say or write in which you mention a person or thing' is essentially an embellishment of 'discourse in which you mention a person or thing': the question remains the same.

Comment: Your question asks about **in which** and your link goes to the term reference. What are you actually saying??  A person or thing is mentioned ***in*** a reference. **The reference in which it is mentioned** is what it refers to.

Comment: _In which_ is a prepositional phrase consisting of the relative pronoun _which_, moved to the beginning of the relative clause, **after** the preposition it was the object of (or, of which it was the object). The whole prepositional phrase is moved, not just the relative pronoun. This process is known in syntax as ["Pied-Piping" the preposition, but it applies to more than prepositions.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299)

Answer (score 0):

"Part of something you say or write in which you mention a person or thing":

A reference is a part of something you say or write = that **something** is your outer shell, and the **part** is the inner **reference** piece.

Inside that something (**in which**), you also **mention** (you quickly say, but just in passing) a different **person or thing**. This inside item is the reference. The term **in which** connects the two halves without repeating **something**.

We would not say *Here is some tea, and the tea will relax you.*

> We would say *Here is some tea, **which** (and the tea) will relax you*.

Likewise, we would not say *Here is some tea, and stirred inside the cup of tea I put honey.*

> We would say *Here is some tea, **in which** (stirred inside the cup of tea ) I put honey.*