# "whose" and "of which"

Tags: relative-pronouns, which-who

I have a question about the usage of "whose" and "of which".
I have learned that

> a. Do you see the mountain whose top is covered with snow?

and

> b. Do you see the mountain the top of which is covered with snow?

have the same meaning.

Now, please consider

> For a nation whose food culture is admired all over the world, Japan depends to a surprising degree on imported food.

If I use "of which" in this, would the correct sentence be

> For a nation the food culture of which is …

or

> For a nation of which the food culture is …?

Comment: It's probably *imported food* not *important food*.

Comment: See also: [ell.se] This question may already have been answered on this site or on [ell.se].

Comment: There is no general rule saying that because a particular rephrasing works in one situation it must work in all similar-looking ones.  'Whose' is a strange beast; it fundamentally refers to people, but its acceptable broadened usage (a toaster whose element has gone) makes it ideal in " ... a nation whose food culture is ..." where 'nation' is arguably abstract but refers to people.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it confused me as I thought "a nation" means "a country" in this context.

Comment: Please, Yok, what did your dictionaries and thesauruses leave unclear?

Comment: Some dictionaries say “the” is needed when nation refers to people. Also, I was not sure of the “of which” grammar. Sorry if I’m not answering your question.

Comment: Thanks, Yok. Please keep reading what  Edwin Ashworth posted, again and again…

Comment: You're asking about the phenomenon known as "Pied-Piping", i.e, when a relative pronoun is embedded in a phrase, the phrase (or smaller subphrases it contains) may be "pied-piped" to the front of the clause when the pronoun itself is moved to the front. Alternatively (the phenomenon is optional), the preposition or other higher-level phrases may simply be left "stranded" at the end of the relative clause. [This answer provides a lot of examples](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299).

Answer (score 1):

> "For a nation **whose** food culture is admired all over the world, Japan depends to a surprising degree on imported food."

In the given context, the reference is to "nation," not in the sense of a geographical entity but of a people. People have culture, people have food habits.

For an inanimate object, *which* would work well. For people, we need to use *whose*. So,

"For a nation **the food culture of which** is admired all over the world, …" would **not** work.

HTH.

As for the specific question of what would the sentence structure be when *of which* is to be used instead of *whose,* the sentence would be, at least hypothetically,:

"For a nation, … of which …"

*Of which* cannot simply take the place of *whose*, they are not the same part of speech, also notice the preposition *of*, so it goes **after** *the food culture*, not before.

"For a nation, the food culture of which is admired all over the world, Japan depends to a surprising degree on imported food."

Comment: Sometimes, *whose* is used for inanimate objects and for animals, but *which* is never used for human beings. I'd myself prefer not to use *whose* for inanimate objects and animals and use *which* instead.