# Dangling Participle?

Tags: participles

Is the following question grammatically correct? "I have found a solution I am happy with."  I've been told the word "with" is a dangling participle.

Comment: Isn't this rather a dangling *preposition*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to end a sentence in a preposition?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16/when-is-it-appropriate-to-end-a-sentence-in-a-preposition)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: The technical term in syntax is a _stranded preposition_. And it doesn't produce ambiguity like a dangling participle, which needs a subject; prepositions don't have subjects. The stranding comes about from the relative clause, which moves a relative pronoun from its position as object of _with_, leaving _with_ stranded at the end of the clause. Perfectly normal behavior in English; the only alternative is [Pied-Piping](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299), which is much more complex and formal: _I have found a solution with which I am happy_.

Answer (score 4):

It isn't a dangling participle, that is a rather different [source of ambiguity](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_30.htm).

Your critic may have been thinking of the "rule" that sentences should not end with a preposition. There is no such rule, so your sentence is fine.

Comment: That is an impertinence up with which I will not put!