# Is it possible that using “whom” these days can slow down and confuse readers and listeners?

Tags: word-usage

In casual conversation, even in written discourse, has English evolved to where using “whom” can slow down readers and confuse listeners ?

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on where the *whom* was in a sentence? Directly after a preposition,  I think *whom* is still used more often than not.

Comment: The general impression I have is: using *whom*, in any context, will cause people to notice you used the word *whom*.  If that's the effect you want for some purpose, then *whom* is the tool for the job. But if you're not trying to draw attention to the words you're using, as opposed to the message you're conveying, then *who* can always be substituted in the modern vernacular.

Comment: It's safe to say that *using* "whom" has become difficult for many native speakers. But whether they have any difficulties *understanding* it, is a different question altogether. I don't think it slows down or confuses anyone when they *see or hear* it. Yes, it can have a color, as Dan Bron explains, but so can many words. Doesn't mean that every single one of them is a roadblock people can't parse past. If you know the word "amaranthine", you know the word "amaranthine". It's colorful but it will only slow you down if you've never seen it before. And everyone has seen the word "whom" before.

Comment: Consider all the native speakers who can't tell the difference between *it's* and *its*. Or *there, their* and *they're*. Or *have* and *of*. They still have no trouble seeing these words being used — including seeing them being used incorrectly. They just breeze straight past them, if anything even faster now than they would if they did care about the difference. You will only really confuse a reader who a) does know the difference, b) does care about it, and most importanly c) you will only succeed by using the word incorrectly in the first place. In all other cases, you are fine.

Comment: Some say that the virtual demise of "whom" is yet another example of the 'dumbing-down' of the language, and that it's no wonder the French think we're nits (or is it nuts?).

Comment: @BillJ Pretty sure people have been caviling about the "dumbing-down" of English since Chaucer, or before.  It's a perennial myth. As for the French, which is more nuts, accepting the world is what it is, or trying to legislate evolution?

Comment: What's evolution got to do with it? It's lazy speech, simple as that.

Comment: @BlJ Language evolves, as life does. One can no more be legislated nor passed judgement on as the other. “Lazy speech” is lazy thinking, and poor linguistics.

Comment: You're right: lazy speech is lazy thinking, which is precisely what we have here. Nothing whatsoever to do with linguistics. And if people want to use "whom", that's a matter for them. Long live "whom"!

Answer (score 4):

I think it has come to that point, at least for a lot of people. As I've been pointing out for decades, there is never any case in English where one **must** use *whom*, but there are an infinite number of cases where one must **not**. Anyone who uses *whom* takes on the responsibility of using it correctly, which means they are implying that they understand enough of English syntax to use it correctly. This is a very difficult claim to justify.

There **is** one situation, as @PeterShor mentions in a comment, where it is required, but that situation is both rare and optional, so one need never go there.

Specifically,

- **If** one forms a relative clause where the relative pronoun refers to a human being, and
- **If** that relative pronoun is the object of a preposition, and
- **If** one optionally decides to use a relative pronoun, instead of omitting it, and
- **If** one optionally decides to use *who* as the relative pronoun, instead of *that*, and
- **If** one optionally applies the rule of [Pied-Piping](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299), which moves the preposition with its object,

**Then**, and only then, is *whom* required. Exemplorum gratia:

- *I threw the ball to Bill.*
- *Bill is the man I threw the ball to.* (relative pronoun deleted)
- *Bill is the man that I threw the ball to*. (*that* instead of *who*, with stranded preposition)
- *Bill is the man who I threw the ball to*. (*who* with stranded preposition)
- *Bill is the man whom I threw the ball to*. (*whom* with stranded preposition)
- *Bill is the man to whom I threw the ball*. (*whom* with Pied-Piped preposition)

In the last sentence above, only *whom* can be used. In the ones previous, it's optional, and one can also use *who*, or *that*, or nothing. So avoid pied-piping and strand those prepositions like a native speaker, and you'll never have to worry about *whom* again.

The main problem is that so few people know the actual rule, but most people think there must be **some** grammatical rule, and they're in the usual Anglophone state of "anxious cluelessness" about syntax, as Geoff Pullum calls it, so they make up some rule that makes sense to them, and follow it. These rules often have nothing to do with grammar per se, but rather about "formality", "correct English", and other vague generalities, and the result can be pretty silly at times. [Like this, for instance.](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html)

And the upshot is that about half the time *whom* is used incorrectly by the actual rule, so anybody who does know it (or anybody who doesn't know it, but has some other rule instead) is likely to pause and check to see whether the speaker or writer knows what they're doing. Often enough, the conclusion is that they don't. Whether they're right or not, they will be perceived as wrong by some.

Comment: Agree. And would add that 'whom' should be used in set phrases, for instance (in fact the only example I can think of right now, though I imagine there are others) if you ever find yourself writing a formal letter to an unknown person and choose the set phrase: to whom it concerns. That would actually look wrong with 'who', but you could also just write 'Dear sir or madam'.

Comment: Fixed phrases are the places where old words go to die. _Whom_ has been on life support for at least a century.

Comment: Who the heck downvoted this? It’s compelling, I can’t find anything to object to.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, but it's politically incorrect, for certain strains of peever politics. Some people pride themselves on knowing The Rule, and take any discussion as a threat to their faith or self-esteem or something. Linguists are used to it.