# Usage of Prepositions + Relative Pronouns

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns

I am going crazy because of **prepositions + relative pronouns**.

Here are some examples and please read and tell me if in the way that I have understood is right or not.

- (1) Do you know the date **when** we have to hand in the essay?

My grammar book says (1) can be changed more formally like (2):

- (2) Do you know the date **on/by which** we have to hand in the essay?

But I do not know if (3) has the same meaning as (1) and (2):

- (3) Do you know the date **which** we have to hand in in the essay **on/by**?

I don't know why I feel like (3) is weird. Maybe, because it is wrong?

It is really confusing because I have known that I can make **Prepositions + which** sentences when prepositions are used with certain verbs like this:

- Playing games **in which** I am interested are good for health.
- Playing games **which** I am interested **in** are good for health.

  ```
                **be interested in**
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process that puts prepositions (as well as other things, occasionally) 
in front of relative
pronouns is called [*Pied-Piping*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299) (honest), and it's very complex syntax, as you can see from the link.

In the case of these sentences, 
there are actually two different questions, depending on whether the essay can be handed in early or not. That's the difference between *on*, which refers to a single day, and *by*, which refers to an end date.

If the essay must be handed in on a particular date, then

- (1) is fine
- (2) is OK with *on* but not with *by*, which implies an end date for the hand-in period
- (3) is grammatical but hopelessly stilted; no native speaker would say this --
        we'd leave out the parts that aren't necessary:
- (4) *Do you know the date we have to hand in the essay?* OR
- (4') *Do you know the date we have to hand in the essay **by**?* (if there is a period with an end date)

or, more likely, we'd just use *when*

- (5) *Do you know when we have to hand in the essay (by)?* (*by* for an end date again)

Comment: Does **in which** modify both (A) and (B), or only (A)? If it only modifies (A), do I need to put **which** in front of **assume** or not? And can I change **in which** into **where** in this case?     <br/>                    
Strategies **in which** (A) only one biological variable is studied or (B) **assume** that a gene causes psychopathology.

Comment: And it seems to me that there are two different ways of making Pied-piping. One is that using **prepositions from … at the end of sentences(?), not related to verbs**, and the other is that using **prepositions from a collaboration of verbs and prepositions such as share with, interfere with, change to**. Have I understood correctly?

Comment: For example, this sentence "The meeting **that** he can share ideas with other scientists **at** it" can be changed to  "The meeting **at which** he can share ideas with other scientists". And, in this case, I don't think that **at** is related to the verb **share** because there is **with**, used with **share**. But this sentence "He met scientists **that** he could **share** ideas **with**" also can be changed to "He met scientists **with whom** he could **share** ideas". So, I think there are two options, maybe more than these. Am I right?...

Comment: Oops, I forgot to say really thank you for letting me know ^^

Comment: You're welcome. There are a number of different sources for prepositions; some do come along with certain verbs, and others are independent. Pied-piping works the same with both.

Comment: My curiosity and doubt about Pied-piping have been solved to some extent. I'm quite happy with it :)  And, would it be alright if I think that there is Pied-piping, it is always formal?

Comment: Oh, yes. Movement rules of associated constituents are remnants of the freer word order that an inflected language provides. Movement towards the beginning of the sentence, especially -- most modern syntactic movement is right-branching, to put heavy constituents at the end of the sentence where they can be parsed more easily (English is a right-branching language).

Answer (score 0):

(1) is incorrect.
(2) and (3) do have the same meaning; the one you use is entirely up to your personal preference; you might feel that (3) is awkward because it ends with a preposition, and this is seen by some to be poor writing. Thus, (2) is the best option, though (3) is technically valid.

Your examples about "to be interested in" are both just as correct as the other.

Answer (score 0):

Example (1) is awkward because “Do you know the date?” and “when” are basically the same question, so “When do we have to hand in the essay?” would be more natural.

Example (2) is technically fine, but extremely formal! I find it hard to imagine circumstances when I would use that level of formality while asking about a due date for class work.

Example (3) is okay but a bit clumsy. There is no problem with the preposition being at the end of the sentence, but the relative pronoun is an object and can be left out (“Do you know the date we have to...”) and it has too many words - “when do we have to...” is simpler.

Your first  ‘playing games’ example is formal in register, and the second can lose the relative pronoun, but the main problem is that the subject is “playing games” so the verb should be “is”, not “are”.