# The all too frequent conundrum involving "who" and "whom": Is it "most of who" or "most of whom"?

Tags: pronouns, whom, who

Sir Reginald Wingate, a British general, is said to have described the Bedouin as “[an untrained rabble, most of whom have never fired a rifle](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2009/05/11/how-david-beats-goliath).”

[Should it not have been "who" instead of "whom" in that sentence fragment](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/400202/337994)?

Google search for "most of who have" returns about 2,70,00,000 results. While a similar search for "most of whom have" returns about About 70,20,000 results. I understand though, from [Laurel](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/191178/laurel), that a more reliable approach would be to either consult the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) or [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most+of+who+have%2Cmost+of+whom+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20who%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20whom%20have%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20who%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20whom%20have%3B%2Cc0).

The problem with the sentence fragment is that it does not sound right substituting "who"/"whom" with "he"/"him".

Comment: Google search's estimates are never accurate. See [Discourage using number of Google results as a source.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/398/191178) for more info.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with your comment. I was also looking at [another post](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83/337994) which prompted me to look at Google results which, as you pointed out, may not be the best way to go about looking for answers in this case.

Comment: Are you writing/speaking things for use by current English speakers? Then there's no need to use whom at all (and the great majority of people don't). Are you interested in how people _used to_  do it? Use 'whom whenever it's a direct or indirect object (like after a preposition like 'to').

Comment: As Mitch says, most native speakers rarely use _whom_ at all. To the extent that they do use it, though, this precise context (as the object of a preposition) is by far the most common one. Even if they don’t use _whom_ in most contexts where it’s possible, a lot of people would use it in this context.

Comment: When it is the object of an immediately preceding preposition, _who_ obligatorily becomes _whom_. This is the only context in which _whom_ is required. And the only way _who_ gets there is if the preposition has been [Pied-Piped](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182720/15299) from its original position along with the _who_. In this case it's the whole determiner phrase _most of_ that's been moved, not just _of_. Pied Piping can go on forever, practically.

Comment: *Most of they have never fired a rifle?* or *Most of them have never fired a rifle?* It's [them](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Most+of+them+have%2C+Most+of+they+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMost%20of%20them%20have%3B%2Cc0).  So, similarly, it's *whom*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using Google search to find frequencies (which is [always laughably inaccurate](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/398/191178)), you can use a tool like English-corpora.org. I used the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and searched for `most of who* have` (where `who*` matches words that start with "who", including "who" itself). The results are clear: there are 108 hits for "most of whom have" and none for anything else. Google NGrams gives [similar results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most+of+who+have%2Cmost+of+whom+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20who%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20whom%20have%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20who%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmost%20of%20whom%20have%3B%2Cc0).

For this sentence it sounds at least slightly odd either way to "substitute *he* and *him* for *who* and *whom*" to figure it out (as [moioci suggests](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/83/191178)). Instead, you can substitute *they* and *them* for *who* and *whom* (the same method, but with plurals):

> ...most of **they/them** have never fired a rifle.

In this sentence, only "them" sounds right.